# Como funciona o ciclo de vida e a visibilidade do objeto Flask.g?

Tags: python-3.x, variáveis, flask

No Flask há um objeto chamado `g` ou `Flask.g` que segundo a [documentação](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/database/) é usado para armazenamento de dados. E este objeto é usado quando se atribui algo para ele.

Por exemplo:

```
def get_db():
    if 'db' not in g:
        g.db = sqlite3.connect(
            current_app.config['DATABASE'],
            detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES
        )
        g.db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

    return g.db
```

Acima em `g.db` é guardada uma instancia de acesso a base de dados. Entretanto, eu tenho algumas dúvidas em relação ao escopo de visibilidade e o ciclo de vida deste objeto `g` durante o seu uso.

## Dúvidas

1. O objeto `g` é visível somente no escopo da requisição e ele é
   liberado da memória assim que a requisição é concluída?
2. O objeto `g` é visível entre Blueprints?
3. O ciclo de vida de `g` é para todo o contexto da aplicação?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. O objeto g é visível somente no escopo da requisição e ele é
   liberado da memória assim que a requisição é concluída?

Sim.

2. O objeto g é visível entre Blueprints?

Sim.  Ele existe enquanto se estiver na mesma requisição - então se em um método de view, você chamar via Python, como uma função, uma função que funcione como view em outro blueprint, ela vera o mesmo "g".

No entanto, naturalmente cada requisição acessa apenas *um* blueprint - onde está configurada a view que respondeu àquela requisição. Uma outra requisição que chame uma função de view em outro blueprint vai "enxergar" um outro objeto "g", diferente do da primeira. E isso é assim ,mesmo que sejam requisições assíncronas feitas quase ao mesmo tempo, e sejam processadas ao mesmo tempo no servidor: requisições diferentes vão ver diferentes objetos de contexto `g`.

3. O ciclo de vida de g é para todo o contexto da aplicação?

O "g" é acessível em qualquer parte e qualquer função da aplicação - mas, de novo, cada requisição vai "ver" um objeto diferente ao fazer "flask.g".

No começo do Flask, o flask.g era simplesmente uma variável do tipo `thread.local` - hoje, com mais formas de atender requisições simultâneas em produção do que simplesmente uma em cada thread, os servidores de aplicação tem que cuidar para que todo o código relacionado a uma requisição veja uma cópia de "g".

A documentação oficial está aqui: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/appcontext/#storing-data

O que causa estranheza sobre o "g" é que de fato não é assim que funcionam variáveis normais - mas é exatamente assim que funcionam os objetos do tipo thread.local.  Criei aqui um pequeno script que demonstra como os atributos dentro de um objeto do tipo `threading.local` são únicos em cada thread:

```
import threading
import time

def worker(number, pause):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    espaco.teste = number
    print(f"thread {number}: Valor de espaco.teste {espaco.teste}")
    time.sleep(pause)
    print(f"thread {number}: Valor de espaco.teste {espaco.teste}")


def main():
    global espaco
    espaco = threading.local()
    espaco.teste = 0
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(1, 1.0))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(2, 0.5))
    print(f"thread princial. Espaco.teste: {espaco.teste}")
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    time.sleep(0.2)
    print(f"thread principal. Espaco.teste: {espaco.teste}")

    t1.join()
    t2.join()

main()
```

A saída desse script fica assim:

```
(env) [gwidion@village tmp01]$ python3 bla10.py 
thread principal. Espaco.teste: 0
thread 1: Valor de espaco.teste 1
thread 2: Valor de espaco.teste 2
thread principal. Espaco.teste: 0
thread 2: Valor de espaco.teste 2
thread 1: Valor de espaco.teste 1
```